# Prospects AIR Android development

Tags: android, mobile, air, air-android

2 months ago my AIR Android app support more than 1100 devices and 706 now. Although this time released a lot of new devices. What is happening?

Still a problem. Even if the app built with AIR captive runtime, Google added "air." as a prefix to the app identifier.